# Any way to tell if a DuplexClientBase is busy?

Tags: wcf

I was looking at Microsoft's duplex WCF sample:

It starts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but the interesting bit is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731935%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at the end with the client.

```
  // Wait for callback messages to complete before
  // closing.
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

  // Close the WCF client.
  wcfClient.Close();
  Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

If you take out the Sleep, you will get an exception

> The session was closed before message transfer was complete.

So clearly the client knows there's stuff in the air, is there a way to ask it for its current status? There's a state but that just defines whether it's open or closed (i.e. connected not active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not entirely true.  Your methods are one-way method calls.  So, when you call the service from your client, that call (or set of calls) is completed.  In other words, the "message" has been delivered to the service and there is no expectation for a response since it is one-way.  It might callback on the callback contract...it might not.

When you setup Duplex channel, you're standing up an endpoint for the service to call back on (client becomes a service essentially).  If you close the client, then if/when the service decides to call back, the communication exception will occur.  That's just the way this message exchange pattern works.

You really sort of answered your own question.  Which is, when you check the status it is either open, closed (or faulted).  When you're using a duplex channel, open in this case means there is potentially "activity" on the channel.  That's why the sleep is there - to allow the service time to call back.   If you look at the SDK sample (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752216(v=vs.110).aspx), it's basically doing the same thing except it sits there waiting for you to press ENTER before it closes the client application.

So, in a real application (not a console based sample like these are), either keep your client proxy active or change your message exchange pattern to a request/reply pattern.

Comment: Yes, in my actual app, I use more of  a pubsub pattern, so after you've called unsubscribe you don't really expect to receive callbacks. What I was suprised about was getting an exception in the client application after closing the wcfClient "early". I'll mark you as correct, because, well you are, but please feel free to comment again.

Comment: That's because of the reliable session that exists for a duplex binding.  After you call a method on your service, the ReliabeSession is going exchange messages (in the channel layer) to guarantee message delivery.  So, from a pure "services" perspective, there are still some messages being exchanged.  They are just not yours - they are ReliableSession messages.  You're shutting things down before these messages can complete.

Comment: Oh I see, that I didn't know. Is there a way to know if the reliableSession is still "active"?

Comment: It's active as long as your channel is open.  The duplex channel provides it automatically and it cannot be turned off.  For other channel types, you can turn it on/off at will.  There's no way to query the channel layer to see the state of "reliable" message exchanges.  I suppose you could write a message inspector and inspect the reliable messaging messages and determine the state on your own as active or not.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess it's safest to always check in case it throws at the end then.